# Округление Ручных Скидок в модуле обмена 1С Битрикс Управление Сайтом - УТ

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Суть вопроса - в интернет магазине со стороны битрикса применяется ручная скидка в целых числах (в данном примере 235). После обмена на стороне 1с получается дробное значение, и соответственно некорректная сумма заказа. Задача - сделать округление скидки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После долгих разборов выяснилось, что проблема в том, что при разборе xml файла, где передаются значения скидки (235) и итоговой суммы заказа (954), модуль обмена БУС высчитывает только процент ручной скидки - отсюда и перерасчет с дробями.

```
ИначеЕсли ОписаниеРеквизита.Значение = "Процент ручной скидки" Тогда
        
        Если НЕ СохраненныеНастройки.НастройкиОбменаЗаказов.УстанавливатьРучнуюСкидкуВДокументе Тогда
        
            Результат = 0;
            
        Иначе   
        
            Если СтрокаXML.Количество = 0 Тогда
                Возврат 0;
            КонецЕсли;
        
            ЦенаДоСкидки =  СтрокаXML.Сумма/СтрокаXML.Количество;
            
            Если ЦенаДоСкидки = 0 Тогда
                Возврат 0;
            КонецЕсли;
            
            лСкидка = 0;
            Если СтрокаXML.Скидки <> Неопределено Тогда
                лСкидка = СтрокаXML.Скидки.Итог("Сумма");   
            КонецЕсли;
            
            Результат = лСкидка*100/(ЦенаДоСкидки+лСкидка);
            
        КонецЕсли;
```

Пробовал делать через настройку загрузки документов - для реквизита Сумма Ручной Скидки задавал <свой алгоритм> [Результат] = [СтрокаXML].Скидки.Итог("Сумма"); (по сути копия кода из получения скидки для расчета ее процента)
Выдается ошибка "Значение не является значением объектного типа (Итог)"
При вариантах [Результат] = [СтрокаXML].Скидки; [Результат] = [СтрокаXML].Скидки.Сумма; [Результат] = [СтрокаXML].Скидка; - тут ловятся ошибки вида "Поле объекта не обнаружено (Сумма)
{(1)}:Параметры.Результат = Параметры.СтрокаXML.Скидки.Сумма;"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Финальным вариантом пробовал просто вручную попытаться расчитать скидку - [Результат] = [СтрокаXML].Цена * [СтрокаXML].Количество - [СтрокаXML].Сумма

Этот вараинт не дал итогов кроме того что процент почему то стал больше[image: введите сюда описание изображения] (скидка была 17, процент должен был быть 1,54)
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как настроить здесь округление ручной скидки.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в своей ошибке - не учитывал то что в заказе есть доставка, где нет скидки, отсюда и ошибки "поле объекта не обнаружено". По итогу в настройках такой код:`

```
                лСкидка = 0;
                Если [СтрокаXML].Скидки <> Неопределено Тогда
                    лСкидка = [СтрокаXML].Скидки.Итог("Сумма"); 
                КонецЕсли;
                лСкидка = лСкидка * [СтрокаXML].Количество;
                [Результат] = лСкидка;
```

`
Умножение на количество - т.к. в xml приходит скидка по 1 шт товара, так выводим полную скидку